# React redux instantiate non-component class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to see how I can instantiate a non-component class with redux.

So I added in a store subscribe:

```
import user from '../helpers/user';
...
store.subscribe(() => {
    user.setState(store.getState().user);
});
export default store;
```

My helper class:

```
class User {
    user: UserState | undefined | null;

    setState(userState: UserState | undefined | null) {
        this.user = userState;
    }
    
    get isAdmin(): boolean {
        return !!(this.user && (this.user.role === USER_ROLE_ADMIN || this.user.role === USER_ROLE_SUPER));
    }

}

export default new User();
```

And I'm using the class properties in react components:

```
import user from '../../helpers/user';

{isAdmin && (...)}
```

But this is not working properly, there seems to be a misuse with the state changes eg. When I login, it doesn't see the updated state so I'd need to add in a `useEffect` to watch for the state change in the component which I'm trying to avoid as I'd like the helper class to manage this. Is there something I'm misunderstanding with redux state?

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your component with redux store, so, when the state of store is changed, it will re-render your component. Document page: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect
For example:

```
const componentA = () => {
  //some logic
  
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     isAdmin: state.user && (state.user.role === USER_ROLE_ADMIN || state.user.role === USER_ROLE_SUPER)
  }
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(componentA)
```

Comment: Yes I know this route but would like to map the state to a helper class instead of doing this for all my components. As asked if it's possible with a non-component class?

Comment: Then I think you can try using a custom Hooks, something like this:

     import user from '../helpers/user';
     function useLoginUser() {
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
   setIsAdmin(!!(user && (user.role === USER_ROLE_ADMIN || user.role === USER_ROLE_SUPER));)
  },[user]);

  return isAdmin;
}
then in your component
const ComponentA = () => {
  const isAdmin = useLoginUser();
  //do something with isAdmin
}
`